# Is there any way to create half moon like multiple circle one inside another in android xml

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas, ellipse

[image: To achieve three semi circle]

In above image i want to create three  ellipse one inside another and on top one half semicircle to right end in xml android so how to achieve this and i have searched on net that with the help of canvas we can do so but i don't know how to do, please help me as it's very hard design given to me to make in android.

i have tried using by changing it's height and width but didn't get close to what is in image .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple custom view that will give you this shape you need to complete it and add more methods for customization for example colors, progress, margins ...etc

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View

class SemiCircleView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val dividerProgressPaint: Paint = Paint()
    private val currentProgressPaint: Paint = Paint()
    private val remainProgressPaint: Paint = Paint()
    private val innerProgressPaint: Paint = Paint()
    private var outerRectangle: RectF? = null
    private var innerRectangle: RectF? = null
    private var margin: Float

    private var progressDivider = .02f
    private var progress: Float = .2f
    private var remainProgress = 1 - progress - progressDivider

    init {
        dividerProgressPaint.color = Color.WHITE
        dividerProgressPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        dividerProgressPaint.strokeWidth = 5f

        remainProgressPaint.color = Color.GREEN
        remainProgressPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        remainProgressPaint.strokeWidth = 5f

        currentProgressPaint.color = Color.RED
        currentProgressPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        currentProgressPaint.strokeWidth = 5f

        innerProgressPaint.color = Color.WHITE
        innerProgressPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        innerProgressPaint.strokeWidth = 5f

        margin = 50f
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        if (outerRectangle == null) {
            outerRectangle = RectF(0f + margin, 0f + margin, width.toFloat() - margin, width.toFloat() - margin)
        }

        if (innerRectangle == null) {
            innerRectangle = RectF(100f, 100f, width.toFloat() - 100f , width.toFloat() - 100f)
        }

        val remainEndAngel = 180 + remainProgress * 180
        canvas.drawArc(outerRectangle!!, 180f, remainProgress * 180, false, remainProgressPaint)

        val dividerEndAngel = remainEndAngel + progressDivider * 180f
        canvas.drawArc(outerRectangle!!, remainEndAngel, progressDivider * 180f, false, dividerProgressPaint)

        canvas.drawArc(outerRectangle!!,dividerEndAngel, progress * 180f, false, currentProgressPaint)

        canvas.drawArc(innerRectangle!!, 180f, 180f, false, innerProgressPaint)
    }
```

The view will look like this without any customization

[image]